# TinyMCE autosave plugin and localStorage

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

By default, TinyMCE's autosave plugin stores the editor's text in localStorage.  Is there a way to tell it to use a different storage engine?  Ultimately what I want to do is set up a listener on the `storeDraft` event so I can persist the contents to our server so the user can access the contents even after the autosave_retention limit has been surpassed.  I know that I can set the autosave_rentention to 0 but even when I do I can see that it still writes the data to localStorage -- it just removes it (though, sometimes not immediately and it seems like a page reload short circuits that in some cases).

So basically, I'd like to hit 2 birds with one stone.  I'd like to stop TinyMCE from storing the data in localStorage and, if I can specify a different "data store", then perhaps I can point it to my ajax handler which will persist to the back end.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

thnx,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `autosave` plugin is designed to work with local storage and has no option to change to a different storage mechanism.  If you want to store the data on your server you would typically that with some custom code that uses either (a) TinyMCE events or (b) a timer to get the editor's current content and then send it to the server.

If you want to use TinyMCE events (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#editorevents) to trigger this process you would have code along these lines:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init change NodeChange Dirty', function (e) {
        // 1. use getContent() to extract the editor's current HTML 
        // 2. send the HTML to your server
      });
    }
});
```

If you want to use a basic timer (e.g. `setTimeout()`) you would use that to trigger the same two actions as the sample code above.

In theory you could modify the `autosave` plugin to send data to your server as opposed to storing the data in local storage but I think you can do what you need in a far simpler way without needing to dig into the ~200 lines of code in the existing plugin.

Comment: That definitely sounds like the best approach.  Thanks!

Ok, slight tangent then -- if I was to implement that solution then how would I be able to replicate the behavior where the autosave button is "inactive" when there is no draft to save but "active" when there is?  I took a look at the autosave plugin and there isn't anything in there regarding the icon.  It looks like the class it uses -- mce-ico mce-i-restoredraft -- is generated dynamically and it's parent gets the mce-disabled class toggled in/out.  What is governing that behavior?  How can I replicate that?

Comment: Actually, answering my own question above (though I'd like confirmation), it seems like that is done in the postRender() function in the plugin? The enabling/disabling of that button?

Comment: You are correct - the plugin both places the buttons in the toolbar and controls when they are active/inactive.